# Compare two values from different tables - MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, workbench

I need to check before insert into 'year' column of ( Academic Report) that it's not less than the year of 'enrollment date' column in (student)

my tables :

```
CREATE TABLE STUDENT
(
 BCN INT (10) ,
 Enrollment_Date timestamp not null default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
 primary key (BCN),          
);


CREATE TABLE ACADEMIC_REPORT
( 
    Stud_Num INT(10) ,
    Year year ,
    primary key (Stud_Num , Year ),

    foreign key (Stud_Num ) references STUDENT( BCN )
    ON DELETE restrict       ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

I've try this :

```
    /* ACADEMIC_REPORT._Year Constraint "BEFORE INSERT" */
delimiter //    
CREATE TRIGGER ReportYearBIN BEFORE INSERT ON  ACADEMIC_REPORT
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   declare  num  int(10);
   SET num= (SELECT BCN
             FROM STUDENT , ACADEMIC_REPORT 
             WHERE BCN = ACADEMIC_REPORT.Stud_Num );

        IF (ACADEMIC_REPORT.Year < YEAR(num.Enrollment_Date))
        THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '10000'
        SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Error....!';
    END IF;
END;
// delimiter ;
```

but it causes this error during insert

```
Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'ACADEMIC_REPORT.Year' in 'field list'
```

How can I do that constraint ?

Using MySql workbench 6.3

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you may need to do this with triggers see http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9662/check-constraint-does-not-work

Comment: `new` is a reference to the incoming row's values for the underlying trigger table. You'll need to `SELECT` from student to get values that you can compare against.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out the problem :)

This statement is completely wrong,

```
 YEAR(num.Enrollment_Date)
```

because it's not correct to write attribute.attribute, you can only use Table.Attribute.

So, here is the solution

```
    /* ACADEMIC_REPORT._Year Constraint "BEFORE INSERT" */
delimiter //    
CREATE TRIGGER ReportYearBIN BEFORE INSERT ON  ACADEMIC_REPORT
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   declare Enroll timestamp;
   SET Enroll = (SELECT Enrollment_Date
                 FROM STUDENT 
                 WHERE BCN = new.Stud_Num);

        IF ( new._year < YEAR(Enroll))
        THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '10000'
        SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Error..The Report year cannot be less than the enrollment year..!';
    END IF;
END;
// delimiter ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I created a select statement for the conditions that you want to generate the error on. If the student exists for this report and the report year is less than the students enrollment date it will generate one or more rows for the select query. The proceeding FOUND_ROWS() will then be greater than 0 which will trigger your error message.

```
CREATE TRIGGER ReportYearBIN BEFORE INSERT ON  ACADEMIC_REPORT
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   SELECT * FROM STUDENT WHERE BCN=new.Stud_Num AND new._year < Enrollment_Date
   IF (SELECT FOUND_ROWS() > 0)
        THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '10000'
        SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Error....!';
    END IF;

END;
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. your code produces this error during create trigger statement  `Error Code: 1415. Not allowed to return a result set from a trigger`